# Calculating AC Input Power

Tags: power-supply, power, measurement, testing

I'm making an AC to DC power supply that connects to mains. There's an AC to DC converter, buck converter and a smoothing LDO that outputs a DC controlled with pots.

I'm verifying the supply, and have been trying to get efficiency measurements. Due to limited equipment, I can only measure input Vrms, input Irms, output DC voltage, and output DC current. However, if I just do the Vdc * Idc/(Vrms * Irms) calculation, my effeciency goes above 100% at the higher loads, which is obviosuly wrong.

I know there's apparent vs real power when driving reactive loads with AC, but when I'm measuring the Vrms and Irms that goes into my circuit, that *is* the real power, is it not? Adding a power factor would mean my circuit becomes even more unphysically efficient.

Is there anything else that I haven't taken into account?

Comment: Vrms * Irms gives you appearant power, while Vdc * Idc is active power. You cannot tell efficiency from the quotient because appearant power also has phase shift and (for a rectifier mostly) current distortion in it.

Answer (score 1):

The product of Irms and Vrms is not real power.

Imagine if the load was a perfect capacitor and input was a pure sine wave.

RMS voltage is mains voltage. RMS current is Vrms/Xc where Xc = \$\frac{1}{2 \pi f C}\$

Say 120VAC RMS and 100\$\mu\$F, so Xc is 1592\$\Omega\$ and Irms is 75.4mA, so we get 9W.

However real power is exactly zero.

To get input power you need to find the average of the instantaneous product of voltage and current. In other words, a wattmeter.

Comment: So measuring Irms and Vrms is really just measuring the apparent power?

Comment: Yes, by definition, the product of the two is apparent power.

Comment: So would I be able to get to the true power delivered from the data I have + an approximation of the reactive and resistive elements or would that be pretty inaccurate?

Comment: Your input is most likely **far** from an ideal reactance. It's probably some spikey waveform (large crest factor). You might be able to use an oscillscope that has appropriate math functions but most are not easily used on mains voltage without danger. For cheap you could try a "Kill-a-Watt" consumer meter.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess the last question I have is, if my current and voltage inputs have some phase shift, that would just be a smaller number than the Irms*Vrms that I have. Then why is my efficiency still greater than 100%? If I use the data I have without accounting for power factor, it should just result in worse efficiency, right?

Comment: If the input is actually a smaller number, then output/input = efficiency is ...

Comment: Larger? Which is exactly my question.

Comment: Yes, provided the meter is reading RMS accurately (not excessive crest factor for the design of meter) it should be an upper limit on efficiency, if I now understand your question...

Comment: What freq are you refering to when the 100 mic cap has 1592 ohms .Is this a really low freq oddball power system ?

Comment: @Autistic oh, probably, but the point is that it's not zero.

Comment: @MichaelE - most likely your RMS current meter is not doing a good job. Keep in mind that the input current waveform will be very different from a sine wave.